# Whoosh - accessing search_page result items throws ReaderClosed exception

Tags: python, full-text-search, whoosh

Following is a simple pagination function.

```
from whoosh import index
def _search(q):
    wix = index.open_dir(settings.WHOOSH_INDEX_DIR)
    term = Term("title", q) | Term("content", q)
    page_id = 1

    with wix.searcher() as s:
        return s.search_page(term, page_id, pagelen=settings.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)

In [15]: p = _search("like")

In [16]: p.results[0].reader.is_closed
Out[16]: True
```

if I try to access an attribute of a Hit, i get ReaderClosed exception.

```
In [19]: p.results
Out[19]: <Top 10 Results for Or([Term('title', 'like'), Term('content', 'like')]) runtime=0.0214910507202>

[21]: p.results[0]["title"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReaderClosed                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/shell.p yc in <module>()
----> 1 p.results[0]["title"]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/searching.pyc in __getitem__(self, fieldname)
1500 
1501     def __getitem__(self, fieldname):
-> 1502         if fieldname in self.fields():
1503             return self._fields[fieldname]
1504 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/searching.pyc in fields(self)
1388 
1389         if self._fields is None:
-> 1390             self._fields = self.searcher.stored_fields(self.docnum)
1391         return self._fields
1392 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/reading.pyc in stored_fields(self, docnum)
1197     def stored_fields(self, docnum):
1198         segmentnum, segmentdoc = self._segment_and_docnum(docnum)
-> 1199         return self.readers[segmentnum].stored_fields(segmentdoc)
1200 
1201     # Per doc methods

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/reading.pyc in stored_fields(self, docnum)
    693     def stored_fields(self, docnum):
    694         if self.is_closed:
--> 695             raise ReaderClosed
    696         assert docnum >= 0
    697         schema = self.schema

ReaderClosed:
```

How can i access hit's attributes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Browsing through whoosh's documents http://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#the-searcher-object I've understood the problem. Leaving it here in case anyone gets stuck with same issue.

Any file descriptor related to search is closed when "with" scope ended. Therefore it seems resultset should be copied into another data structure such as a list of dictionaries in the "with" block, to be used outside the block.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue, your answer helped me!

Comment: I had the same problem and this confirmed my suspicions, thanks!

Comment: I found that a for loop, a list comprehension or a yield all gave me the error, until I accessed a property of each map in the loop